# Getting Server Name Right - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a remote Windows Server 2017 with MS SQL Server and I want to connect with it remotely from my machine (but currently I'm unable to).
First of all I want to ask if I get the IP address right (or rather Server Name field in SQL Server prompt in MS SQL Server Management Studio)

[mentioned server name field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiHnS.jpg)

Let's say IP of the remote server is 135.150.96.96. The instance of the SQL Server on remote server is "TEST". The port is 63011. If I'm one of admins on remote server I assume this server works all the time for all users.

```
135.150.96.96\TEST,63011
```

Is this address correct?

I know there are more things to check (services, firewall etc.) that's why I want to be sure I type server name correctly.

Comment: this is correct, try connecting and post the error if you face any.

Comment: If you are connecting directly to a port, specifying the instance name is superfluous.

Comment: OK. Thank you Shareef.

Comment: Use either `135.150.96.96\TEST` or `135.150.96.96,63011`. I don't know if the syntax you mentioned is correct. It's disappointing (but alas not suprising) that you didn't actually try it

Comment: Nick I tried many combinations, that's why I'm asking for help. Given the proper syntax I can start changing other things. I have a starting point. Thanks for answer. Jeroen you too.

Comment: When you try something and it does not work it is a good idea to include the error message in your question.  Right now we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: destination-data, I have my answer regarding ip address. Hopefully I'll simplify the rest of the process for me.